# Why my Timer is repeating?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I'm creating a Timer that fires an event everytime it finishes (1900 ms), and continues doing that. But when I stop it, and then start it again, the event fires twice, and if I stop and start it again, it fires the event three times, and so on. 
How can I avoid that? thanks.

```
        public static System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        public static void ChequearRecepcion()
        {
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 1900;
            aTimer.Start();     
        }

        public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            EnviarConsulta();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event is being fired multiple times from the event happening once because you are assigning to the event multiple times.

`aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);`

Notice how the syntax is `+=`, not `=`. That means every time this code is run a new handler will be added to the event, not just reassigned. Each handler that has been added will run when the event is fired. Thus if you started and stopped it three times, then three event handlers have been added and each will run the code.

You need to assign an event handler to the event once, probably in the constructor instead of in `ChequearRecepcion`. Another option that might be what you're looking for is to remove the event handler when you stop the timer.

`aTimer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);`

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching the event every time the method `ChequearRecepcion` is called.

In the method where you stop the timer, which you didn't include, you can unsubscribe from the event, or you can create an instance of the timer only once (in the constructor of your class, most likely) and subscribe to the event at that point and only at that point.